# CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) being removed after/during UPDATE to Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

First off I apologize about how the pictures came through... The pictures I attached did not come through very well and get bigger if you click on them. Sorry about that.

I have a gridview cell populated by MSSQL Database that I am trying to make look nice that consists of a first name, last name, email, and phone number.  Currently it looks like this:

[image: Gridview Cell I want to change]

I want to have it formatted so that Name, email, and phone are on separate lines.

First of all the select command looks like this: Notice the CHAR13 + CHAR10
[image: Select Command]

When the code behind gets to the update command the cmd text shows this is what will be updated: notice it is changing the CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) to different code.

[image: Update Command]

Finally when I look at the data in the database it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It would be far better to store *separate* pieces of data in *separate* columns, and only combine them when *presenting* them to users.

Comment: How about posting the code here, instead of pictures of the code?

Comment: I Agree with Damien - It is far easier to separate the name, email etc and combine them in runtime. And I have one additional tip: This kind of data is a waste of your money to run in a relational database. You can easilly run this 1000 faster at a fraction of the cost of an ER system. Only use ER databases like MsSql for transactional needs, nothing more.

Comment: RE: "Finally when I look at the data in the database it looks like this:" results sets in SSMS shows in Grid never show line breaks in results. Use "Results to Text" option (shortcut: CTRL+T) to display your results as text in SSMS. This will give messy output but you will see if your text splits.

Comment: RE: "When the code behind gets to the update command." If by different code you mean "vbCrLf", then just Google it's meaning.